# Get HWD media share video thumbnail url from Joomla database

Tags: joomla-3.x, database, jdatabase

I have videos on my site component HWDmedia share. They haven't schema.org integration and trying add markup to videos. For videoobject have 4 types and i add 3 of them (name,description and date) but have problems with thumbnails. As video from youtube loading with iframe thumbnails also loading in iframe, but it also adding to database. 
I try to add code from joomla documentation to get that url

```
<?php
// Get a db connection.
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
 // Create a new query object.
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

$query
    ->select($db->quoteName(array('id', 'thumbnail')))
    ->from($db->quoteName('ojn5g_hwdms_media'));

$db->setQuery($query);
$row = $db->loadRow();
print_r($row);
?>
```

But in result i get

```
stdClass Object ( [id] => 28 [thumbnail] => )
```

Comment: On a side note, please replace `ojn5g_` with `#__`, which is the generic Joomla database table prefix. As for the thumbnail, have you checked in PhpMyAdmin that the value actually exists?

Comment: I use this code `<?php
// Get a db connection.
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
 // Create a new query object.
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

$query
    ->select($db->quoteName(array('thumbnail')))
    ->from($db->quoteName('ojn5g_hwdms_media'))
 ->where($db->quoteName('id') . ' LIKE '. $db->quote(46));

$db->setQuery($query);
$row = $db->loadRow();
print_r($row);
?>`                 
and get result 
`Array ( [0] => https://i.ytimg.com/vi/SXTOwG1XhSM/maxresdefault.jpg )`
that correct but i need get this thumbnails from database and check if thumbnail of this video or no. How can i do it?

Answer (score 1):

I already solve my problem 
Here is code

```
 <?php
/// Get a db connection.
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
 // Create a new query object.
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query
    ->select($db->quoteName(array('id','thumbnail')))
    ->from($db->quoteName('#__hwdms_media'));

$db->setQuery($query);
$results = $db->loadObjectList();
$thisitem = $this->item->id; // HWD media share this item id 
$objectoarr = json_decode(json_encode($results),true); // Convert stdClass object to array

foreach ($objectoarr as $thumbnail) {
    if ($thumbnail['id'] == $this->item->id) {
        // Do something with $thumbnail['id'] and $thumbnail['thumbnail']
      $medthumb = $thumbnail['thumbnail'];
      echo "<meta itemprop=\"thumbnailUrl\" content=\"$medthumb\"/>";// 
    }
}

?>
```